# Pandas merge in a function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use pandas merge in a function as shown below.

Here is what I am trying to use :

```
test = inv_level(left, right, 'user_id', 'new_id', 'left') #left.merge(right, on='user_id', how='left')
```

where inv_level is a function as defined below

```
def inv_level ( child_inv, parent_inv, lefton, righton, how ):
    level_inv = pd.merge(parent_inv, child_inv, left_on=lefton, right_on=righton, how=how)
    return level_inv
```

When I use merge directly without a function it works fine. But, when I use merge in a function and call the function passing parameters, it throws an error. I am not sure what exactly is the issue. I appreciate your input/support.

File "C:\temp\env\3.8.6\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1005, in _get_merge_keys right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk)) File "C:\temp\env\3.8.6\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1563, in _get_label_or_level_values raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 'new_id'

Thanks,

Following is the complete program.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def inv_level ( child_inv, parent_inv, lefton, righton, how ):
    level_inv = pd.merge(parent_inv, child_inv, left_on=lefton, right_on=righton, how=how)
    return level_inv


def main(event, context):
    np.random.seed(0)
    # transactions
    left = pd.DataFrame({'transaction_id': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
                        'user_id': ['Peter', 'John', 'John', 'Anna'],
                        'value': np.random.randn(4),
                    })
    # users
    right = pd.DataFrame({'new_id': ['Paul', 'Mary', 'John', 'Anna'],
                        'favorite_color': ['blue', 'blue', 'red', 
                                            np.NaN],
                        })

'''
    test = inv_level(left, right, 'user_id', 'new_id', 'left') #left.merge(right, on='user_id', how='left')
     The above throws an error
'''
    test = pd.merge(left, right, left_on='user_id', right_on='new_id', how='left') 

    print(test)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("", "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not swapped `parent_inv` and `child_inv`, so in your solution was tested column `new_id` in `left` instead `right`:

```
#swapped DataFrames
def inv_level (parent_inv, child_inv, lefton, righton, how ):
```